# Hypothetically, I

Tags: riddle, wordplay

Hypothetically, I
am an infix for raising you high
am an infix for tearing apart
am an infix for what relies on your heart

Am the reverse of the start of your health
am an infix for the start of much wealth
Am an infix for a thing with a blade
Am the reverse of the start of an aid

Hint:

> Somewhere above in this verse
>  I'm listed five times in reverse.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're an

> if

because of

> an infix for raising you high (l-IF-t),
>  am an infix for tearing apart (r-IF-t?)
>  am an infix for what relies on your heart (your l-IF-e)
>  Am the reverse of the start of your health (FItness)
>  am an infix for the start of much wealth (gIFt or thrIFt?)
>  Am an infix for a thing with a blade  (a knIFe)
>  Am the reverse of the start of an aid (a FIx?)

and of course

> a "what if?" is a hypothetical, and "fi" appears five times in the riddle (each in the word "inFIx")